# primefaces codeMirror doesn't load his own css and js

Tags: javascript, css, primefaces, codemirror, primefaces-extensions

I want to use codeMirror from primeface-extension with an sql syntax.

I've got a 404 error when the page who contains this component load. The Css and javascript component not found.

My code is the same as the example from showcase-ext codeMirror.

Using primefaces 5.1 and primefaces-ext 2.1.0.

Does anyone have this problem?

Thank you in advance.

edit:

my jsf:

```
    <pe:codeMirror id="codeMirror"
    value="#{sandboxBean.content}" lineNumbers="true"/>  

    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{sandboxBean.changeMode}" update="codeMirror"  
             value="Change mode with AJAX" style="margin-top:10px;"/>
```

my bean:

```
private String content;  
private String mode = "javascript";  

public void changeMode() {  
    if (mode.equals("css")) {  
        mode = "javascript";  
    } else {  
        mode = "css";  
    }  
}  

public List<String> complete(final CompleteEvent event) {  
    final ArrayList<String> suggestions = new ArrayList<String>();  

    suggestions.add("context: " + event.getContext());  
    suggestions.add("token: " + event.getToken());  

    return suggestions;  
}  

public String getContent() {  
    return content;  
}  

public void setContent(final String content) {  
    this.content = content;  
}  

public String getMode() {  
    return mode;  
}  

public void setMode(final String mode) {  
    this.mode = mode;  
}
```

The error on my browser console: 404 (Introuvable) for css and js of primefaces component.

The other primefaces component load correctly so i doesn't understand why this one not work.

What's wrong in my code ?

Comment: This is more like a discussion post. Instead of just describing problem and asking if anyone had same, put your code and ask for solution. Please understand that, with good questions answers will be more valuable and reachable.

Comment: I understand. I add my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got the same error and managed to make it work adding resources-codemirror dependency to my pom.xml

```
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId> 
        <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId> 
        <version>3.2.0</version> 
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>resources-codemirror</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```