# Primefaces extension codemirror error

Tags: primefaces, codemirror, primefaces-extensions

primefaces extension code mirror is not working as expected.
Loaded primefaces 6.1 and its supporting jar's.
commons-lang3-3.1,gson-2.2.4,primefaces-extensions-6.1.0

primefaces-extensions-6.1.0- doesn't have resources.primefaces.extensions.codemirror and got the below error

```
 WARNING [org.primefaces.util.ResourceUtils] (default task-58) Resource not 
found, ignore it. Name: codemirror/codemirror.js, Library: primefaces-
extensions
```

. 
I added those css and js manually.
Now completemethod is not firing and got the below exception in browser.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
at eval (<anonymous>)
at jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:14
at Function.globalEval (jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:14)
at text script (jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:25)
at af (jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:25)
at cf (jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:25)
at i (jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:25)
at Object.send (jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:25)
at Function.ajax (jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:25)
at Function.bH._evalUrl (jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:25)
```

link of jar files used:

https://files.fm/u/ak23jeht

Comment: Possible duplicate of [primefaces codeMirror doesn't load his own css and js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422935/primefaces-codemirror-doesnt-load-his-own-css-and-js)

Comment: Add https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces.extensions/resources-codemirror/6.1.0

Comment: @JasperdeVries same console exception Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at VM46 jquery.js.xhtml:14
    at Function.globalEval (VM46 jquery.js.xhtml:14)
    at text script (VM46 jquery.js.xhtml:25)
    at af (VM46 jquery.js.xhtml:25)
    at cf (VM46 jquery.js.xhtml:25)
    at i (VM46 jquery.js.xhtml:25)
    at Object.send (VM46 jquery.js.xhtml:25)
    at Function.ajax (VM46 jquery.js.xhtml:25)
    at Function.bH._evalUrl (VM46 jquery.js.xhtml:25)

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of jQuery? If not, you should probably report an issue at GitHub.